# Change boot order when rEFInd Boot Manager seems lost

Tags: dual-boot, startup, macosx, grub-efi, startup-applications

I originally installed a dual boot system Mac OS X + Ubuntu [using EFI as the start up by following [How to Install and Dual-Boot Ubuntu on Mac](https://www.maketecheasier.com/install-dual-boot-ubuntu-mac/)]. As predicted, Ubuntu took over the start order so I used this cmd to change the order.

```
sudo efibootmgr -o
```

It was working fine until today. As my system kept on starting into Ubuntu I assumed it was because of a grub update (because I didn't disable these) as described by https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootcoup.html#efibootmgr so thought that I needed to change the order again but it seems as if the rEFInd has been lost.

I need to restart my system into the OS X (to work - I use Adobe CC). However when I went to change the order I had the following error:

```
pikachu@r3dpi11:~$ sudo efibootmgr -o 0080, 0000
Malformed BootOrder order0080,
```

These are the details of my drives as they are now:

```
pikachu@r3dpi11:~$ sudo efibootmgr
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 5 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0080
Boot0000* ubuntu
Boot0080* Mac OS X
Boot0081* Recovery OS
BootFFFF* 

pikachu@r3dpi11:~$ sudo efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 5 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0080
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,7732e79d-d187-4690-8909-ea0639cf51fe,0x28,0x64000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0080* Mac OS X  HD(1,GPT,7732e79d-d187-4690-8909-ea0639cf51fe,0x28,0x64000)/File(\EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi)
Boot0081* Recovery OS   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(3,GPT,2ec859a0-61e4-4e84-a559-3d61ff284ff7,0x576d9410,0x135f20)/File(\com.apple.recovery.boot\boot.efi)
BootFFFF*   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(3,GPT,2ec859a0-61e4-4e84-a559-3d61ff284ff7,0x74678200,0x135f20)/File(\System\Library\CoreServices\boot.efi)
```

When I use the Ubuntu GUI disk utility it does still show the EFI partition.

[image: screenshot of the disk utility]

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS GNOME: 3.28.2

Many thanks to anyone who can help.

In case this helps:

```
$ bootctl status
System:
     Firmware: n/a (n/a)
  Secure Boot: disabled
   Setup Mode: user

Current Loader:
      Product: n/a
          ESP: n/a
         File: └─n/a

Boot Loader Entries in EFI Variables:
        Title: ubuntu
           ID: 0x0000
       Status: active, boot-order
    Partition: /dev/disk/by-partuuid/7732e79d-d187-4690-8909-ea0639cf51fe
         File: └─/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi

        Title: Mac OS X
           ID: 0x0080
       Status: active, boot-order
    Partition: /dev/disk/by-partuuid/7732e79d-d187-4690-8909-ea0639cf51fe
         File: └─/EFI/refind/refind_x64.efi

        Title: Recovery OS
           ID: 0x0081
       Status: active
    Partition: /dev/disk/by-partuuid/2ec859a0-61e4-4e84-a559-3d61ff284ff7
         File: └─/com.apple.recovery.boot/boot.efi

        Title: 
           ID: 0xFFFF
       Status: active
    Partition: /dev/disk/by-partuuid/2ec859a0-61e4-4e84-a559-3d61ff284ff7
         File: └─/System/Library/CoreServices/boot.efi
```

Comment: I couldn't find a way and needed to get back to my OSX so restarted in OSX recovery mode. Ended up with a number of other issues so decided to delete ubuntu see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/843875/delete-ubuntu-dual-boot-on-mac-w-refind

Answer (score 0):

I used the exact same guides as the OP. Apparently, you have to re-run the `refind-install` script. I did it from the recovery mode of Mac OSX (so I restarted pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, opened a

> Utils -> Terminal

and ran the script from its location - you will have to navigate to it using `cd`, or use e.g. the `find` command-. Once you are in the right folder, run it  using

```
./refind-install
```

i.e. without the sudo. In my case it threw, among other lines:

```
...
Found suspected Linux partition(s); installing ext4fs driver.
Installing driver for ext4 (ext4_x64.efi)
...
```

After restart, the rEFInd menu re-appeared with all the expected options (including Mac OSX and Ubuntu). I hope this helps someone.

**Note:**
Maybe it's also possible to run the `refind-install` script from Ubuntu itself, I did not try it.